# Calculate percentage on SSRS Expressions

Tags: sql, reporting-services, reportbuilder3.0

I have the following table on SQL:

```
Category  |   Requests
Cat1      |   150
Cat2      |   200
Cat3      |   550
Cat4      |   100
Cat5      |   50
SUM       |   1050
```

How can  create an expression to calculate the percentage of Cat5 compared to the total? (4.7% in this case).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
=Lookup("Cat5",Fields!Category.Value,Fields!Requests.Value,"DataSetName")/
Sum(Fields!Requests.Value,"DataSetName")
```

Replace `"DataSetName"` by the actual name of your dataset.

Comment: Thank you! this is what i ended up doing: =1 - (Lookup("none",Fields!Category.Value,Fields!Requests.Value,"dataset")/Sum(Fields!Requests.Value, "dataset"))

Comment: In your question you said 4.7%, that's the result my expression provides. I hope it helps you.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want 150 to represent 150% within the rdl you can do the following:

first apply the following formula: `=Fields!field.Value/100`

Where `Fields!field.Value` is the field you want to convert to percentage so if your field is called Requests then you will have  `=Fields!Requests.Value/100`

[image]

Then you need to change the type of the textbox to be percentage from the TextboxProperties

[image]

you should get a result like this:

[image]